# How would you go about creating a random spawner for coins within a certain area? It has to re-spawn coins after the player has collected enough too

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have a coin which rotates and changes size so far. I want to be able to set an area (which is not a nice square of course) that they can randomly spawn locations. The thing it has to do is once there are less that 7 coins then it spawns more.

Anyone able to give me some advice? Not sure what is most efficient method.

Comment: Heyo, do you have any code to share from your attempt to solve it? What piece of this are you having trouble with? Spawning the objects? Choosing random locations within a square? And did you run into any errors when you attempted it?

Comment: I haven't got any code for it because i really don't know how to go about it. I did do some research and it varies to local scripts, magnitude, cframe, raycasting... so i am trying to get an opinion about what is actually recommended.

Comment: I personally recommend setting spawn locations manually, if possible. Looks better, and is usually less buggy.

Comment: @Luke100000 Can you still randomise it ?

Comment: If you're looking for a place to start, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178823/how-to-optimize-an-overuse-of-if-statements-in-roblox-studio/73186850) was rather similar. It's not exactly what you're asking, but it might be a helpful place to start

Comment: Really stupid question here: How do i put the position in a table? I am trying bits of code off the optimization thread you suggested/the manual spawn locations

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be making use of [ZonePlus](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/zoneplus-v320-construct-dynamic-zones-and-effectively-determine-players-and-parts-within-their-boundaries/1017701) and its [`getRandomPoint`](https://1foreverhd.github.io/ZonePlus/api/zone/#getrandompoint) function.

If you want a direct reference, [the creator of the module made a playground and its source code is publicly viewable](https://www.roblox.com/games/6166477769/ZonePlus-Playground). The playground contains a 'CoinSpawner' (literally what you're looking for).

Comment: I will give that a go in the morning. Sounds exactly what I need. Just checked their game demo and it seems overpowered. Haha, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can either make use of "Region3" or you can set up multiple possible spawn points and run a math.random function to choose which one.